# New Data Not Updating after Unwind Segue Performed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, unwind-segue

I'm relatively new to Swift and am stumbling on this problem that is likely very simple to fix, I just can't figure it out and keep hitting a brick wall.

I'm making an app where a user taps an image in a collection view controller and it performs an unwind segue back to the main view controller and updates a uiimageview with the image that the user selected.  I got the unwind segue to work but the problem is that the uiimageview is always one image behind (i.e. I select image A, unwind segue back and no image displays, so I select image B unwind segue back and then the original image I selected the first time, image A, is in the uiimageview).

Here is the code for the destination view controller (main view controller where I want the uiimageview to update based on the image selected in the collection view)...

```
 @IBAction func unwindToVC(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if(segue.sourceViewController .isKindOfClass(FrancoCollectionCollectionViewController))
    {
        let francoCollectionView:FrancoCollectionCollectionViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! FrancoCollectionCollectionViewController
        let selectedImageFromLibrary = selectedFranco
        dragImage!.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageFromLibrary)
    }
```

On the collection view controller where the user selects the image and it unwinds back, I just ctrl + dragged the cell to "exit" on the storyboard and selected the unwindToVC segue.

As far as my collection view here is how I have that set up, since I have a suspiscion it's related to the didSelectItemAtIndexPath part of it but I'm not sure...

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return francoPhotos.count 
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FrancoCellCollectionViewCell

    // sets each cell of collection view to be a uiimage view of francoPhotos

    let image = UIImage(named: francoPhotos[indexPath.row])
    cell.francoImageCell.image = image

    return cell
}

    // highlights cell when touched 
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedFranco = francoPhotos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

}
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    }
```

Sorry if I posted way too much code but this is my first post and like I said I'm new to development, so I figured it would be better to include a little extra rather than not have something that is needed.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!!! :)

Comment: not sure if this will help because that's a mighty problem to solve for SO. It may take a lot of work to solve this. But after the unwind happens, how about hitting a reload on the collectiionView? So, in the viewwillappear or viewdidappear or viewdidlayoutsubviews or some other custom method, you call to reload in the collectionview

Comment: Kate, what specifically is the issue you are having when you say you are hitting a wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is called after the segue is triggered.  So, it is always one behind.

One way to fix this is to call the *unwind segue* programmatically with `performSegueWithIdentifier` instead of wiring it from the cell to the exit.  To do this, wire your exit segue from the *viewController* icon (left most icon) at the top of your viewController to the *exit icon* (right most icon).

[image: wire programmatic exit segue]

Find this segue in the *Document Outline* view and give it an *identifier* such as `"myExitSegue"` in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right.  Then in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, the last thing to do is to call `performSegueWithIdentifier("myExitSegue", sender: self)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

Remove the code in the source VC unwind action for an empty unwind segue like so (the logic for displaying the new image will be put in the collection VC):

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

Give your unwind segue a string identifier so that you may perform the segue programmatically not automatically. Here, I just called mine "Unwind".

[image]
[image]

Then, inside of `FrancoCollectionCollectionViewController` put a property to hold the selected UIImage:

```
var selectedFranco: UIImage!
```

Within `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` set the property to the selected image and then manually perform the segue:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // ... 
    self.selectedFranco = francoPhotos[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Unwind", sender: self)
}
```

Then I would add the `prepareForSegue` method in your `FrancoCollectionCollectionViewController` to set the source view controller's image to the selected image:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Unwind" {
        let sourceVC = segue.destinationViewController as! YourSourceViewController
        sourceVC.dragImage.image = selectedImageView.image
    }
}
```