# swift 2 search bar will be not hidden after unwind segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

in my swift 2 app i have a table view controller with a search bar.
i setup the search bar in my viewDidLoad. and in the viewWillAppear i set the offset of my tableView, because i would like to hide the search bar on start. this works finde.

but if I switch to another view controller and go back to the TableViewController with an exit unwind segue, the search bar will be directly visible.

if I go back to my TableViewController from another view controller with an normal modal segue (not unwind), the search bar will be hidden, because the tableview.setContentOffset will be active.

any ideas what i do wrong?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var items = [CoreData_ITEMS]()


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {}

    func DatenAbrufen() {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ITEMS")      
            do {
                try self.items = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [CoreData_ITEMS]
            } catch { }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }




/*************** VIEW DID LOAD ***************/
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }






    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        DatenAbrufen()
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,44) 
    }



    /*************** ANZAHL DER ZELLEN ERMITTELN ***************/
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }


    /*************** ZELLEN MIT INHALT FÜLLEN ***************/
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ModifyCells


        var ITEM:CoreData_ITEMS
        ITEM = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.Name.text = ITEM.name
        return cell
    }



    /*************** EXIT FUNKTIONEN ***************/
    @IBAction func exit_to_TViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The thing is that `tableView.contentOffset` does not get set unless the tableview is displayed on the screen. I don't know why it has this behaviour. So what fixed it for me was moving the `tableView.contentOffset` call to `vieDidAppear` but then the scrolling is a bit visible. This wasn't a problem for me. If you don't want that you could try moving the call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: i put this call into the `viewDidAppear` => same Result like post 1. i put this call in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` => Serch Bar is now hidden the whole time. but now i cant scroll down the table view to show the search bar ...

Comment: Also try using `tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)` instead of `tableView.contentOffset =`

Comment: okay, if i put this into the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` on first start i see how the table will scroll down and the search bar will be hidden. but if scroll up (to show the search bar) the table will automatically scroll down again - every time. in the `didappear` i had the same issue like post 1

Comment: Well it should work on `didAppear` make sure u do not call `reloadData` after you set the content offset, it might also have something to do with it.

Comment: Also I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34008038/1949494 . If you wire the unwind segue to a button directly this might also cause a problem.

Comment: the didAppear part will always execute After the reloadData. i check this. @Jelly: i call the unwind segue only programmatically

Comment: My guess is that something is happening after you set the offset. To check this you could set the offset in a `dispatch_after` block with a delay of lets say a second in `didAppear`. This should show you if something is changin back your offset after you set it or not.

Comment: okay now i try this: `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,44), animated: true)
        })` and this works fine. but it is mysterious. i call in each func and method a print() and the DidAppear is the last print in the log. why i have to use dispatch ?

Comment: Well you shouldn't, I said you should do this just for testing. I think `reloadData` does something asynchronous in its implementation that messes this up. You could try calling `self.tableView layoutIfNeeded()` after `reloadData`.

Comment: i comment the reloadData out for testing, but the issue stays the same ... i guess it can't be a problem with the reload data

Comment: Do you do some kind of async operations on the tableview?

Comment: Could you also post the code where you do the unwind?

Comment: in the `viewWillAppear` it is only this part: `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("exitVC", sender: self)`

Comment: Try calling `self.performSegueWithIdentifier...` on a button action or something, not on `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: i try it with an alert action button. same issue

Comment: I don't have time right now, I'll do a sample project trying this later and I'll update my answer, if you won't find the issue.

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM. the VC which execute the unwind segue, has active the option `Hide Bottom Bar on Push`in the StoryBoard. If i disable this option, the search Bar will be hidden after unwind segue. but i need this option. how can i solve this ?

Comment: Maybe you tableview gets resized and this is why it doesn't get scrolled. Did you try setting a bigger value, like 88?

Comment: please look at my last comment

Comment: I saw that but the tool bar has a height maybe that height is equal with the amount you scroll and when the tableview is resized (on show/hide toolbar) the search bar becomes visible. Also you could try setting `hide bottom bar on push programatically` before unwinding like `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false` before you do the unwind call. But I doubt this would work.

Comment: `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false` doesn't work and if I change the value from 44 to 88 , same issue

Comment: Another idea would be to sublass `UIToolbar` and implement some delegate methods like `didShow` and `didHide` and perform the scrolling on those.